# IF statement: IF cell is blank, leave blank, if not display 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I would like column G to reference cells in column A. IF column A does not have a value in it, I would like the cells in column G to be blank. IF cells in column A have values in it, I would like cells in column G to display "1".

The cells in column A have a formula in it referencing a different sheet.

The formula I have so far is:

> G1=IF(ISBLANK(A1), G1="", 1)

Right now, it displays "1" in column G because there is a formula in column A

> A1=JE!C7

but I only need it to display "1" if there is actual data from the other sheet, "JE", in it.

If anyone know if a work around, I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `A1=""`. ISBLANK() will not return true if there is a formula in A1 even if that formula returns `""`.

Also `G1=""` is incorrect, you only need to put the `""`.

Use this formula:

```
=IF(A1="","", 1)
```

---

In A1 I put the following formula:

```
=IF(1=1,"",1)
```

And as you can see in G1 it returns `""` and not 1.

[image]

Comment: That is what I used at first but when there is no data in A1, G1 still displays "1", when it should be blank. I think it is because there is a formula in A1. When I delete the formula in A1, G1 is blank, as it should be. Is there a way I can work around this?

Comment: did you try the formula I posted, if there is a formula in A1 that returns `""` this will work.  You need to make sure though that it is returning `""` and not `" "` with a space between.

Comment: I added the space to " ", unfortunately, it still didn't work. I have a formula in the cells inside column A that is preventing the formula from working as I'd like. Is there a way I can sort of hide the formula inside the formula in column G? In other words, so the formula in column A doesn't interfere with the formula in column G?

Answer (score -1):

try this formula

`=IF(OR(A12="",ISBLANK(A12)),"",1)`

This should fix the issue

Comment: A blank cell gives true on `=""` as well, so this is redundant.